# How do you jump in Neverball?

Tags: neverball

I was playing neverball,  well the video clearly shows you could jump over a corner, but it didn't tell you how to do that actually?

Is there a special key to press by the corner?

[image: screenshot of Neverball]

I'm just not sure how to `take a aim`.

Answer (score 1):

If this is anything like other ball-rolling games, here's what they probably mean:

Get some speed up towards an edge and just before you fall off, tilt the world the *opposite direction* sharply.  That will raise the (previously lowered) edge you were travelling towards, and throw you into the air.

You may have to return the tilt to your original slope after launching to make a successful landing, depending on the physics of the game.

Comment: Here's a Youtube video that sort of confirms this: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pqSIXupmixk, im still not sure *how* exactly he managed to pull that of